# Why position fixed div goes to outside of the main container?

Tags: css

Given below the fixed div CSS:

```
.top-container {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: 999;
}
```

When I zoom out my screen, this div breaks the main container at the right side but left side is okay. Check below screenshot for better understanding.

[image]

Comment: OK, so what's your question?

Comment: I want the right side of the fixed div not to go outside of the main container div like left side. You see left side is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You have to understand how `position: fixed;` is working. It ignores any surrounding element.

You can find detailed information [here](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/).

Here's a quote:

> A fixed position element is positioned relative to the viewport, or the browser window itself.

**UPDATE**
What you can try is to use a `margin-left` same as the left element's width and `margin-right` same as the right element's width to the `.top-container` element. This is obviously not an ideal solution but solves your problem.

Comment: It seems my fixed div ignores only right side not the left side today!!

Comment: This is not fully true, only if a _horizontal_ (`left`, `right`) or _vertical_ (`top`, `bottom`) position is set, then it will ignore the surrounding element for this particular axis: [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u79krtec/), I would even guess the behavior of Chrome for the `hover` in this sample [jsfiddle demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/u79krtec/1/) is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I am late to answer this for this question but I am sure this is a common problem to exist in future and will help the future searchers.

This can be solved by applying a trick. We can use `calc` here.

```
.your-class {
  position: fixed;
  right: calc((100vw - 90%)/2);
}
```

This worked for me. Please note that in my case I intended the floating element to be shifted on the right side. If you want it on the left please use `left` instead of right.